# Using batch file, how to name a file like year_month with date increased in 1 month from now?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to name a file with the following format:

2019-11

2019-12

2020-01

Basically, name a file with the date increased in 1 month from now using batch file

Comment: `Ren 2019-12 2020-01`, `Ren 2019-11 2019-12`, `Ren 2019-10 2019-11`, `Ren 2019-09 2019-10`, `Ren 2019-08 2019-09`, `Ren 2019-07 2019-08`, `Ren 2019-06 2019-07`, `Ren 2019-05 2019-06`, `Ren 2019-04 2019-05`, `Ren 2019-03 2019-04`, `Ren 2019-02 2019-03`, and `Ren 2019-01 2019-02` seems a good start. I won't offer some crazy convoluted batch file to workaround the fact that everything is a string not a date object. I would suggest you abandon batch files, and use a more suitable scripting language. WSH and PowerShell are both available to most Windows users and can still be run from batch files.

Comment: Without knowing more, Compo's solution is definitely the best that can be offered, wirhour guessing wildly.

Comment: I'll also add that a file is usually named using the following format, `filename.ext`, so in your case, I'd expect your filenames to perhaps be `2019-11.zip`, `2019-12.log`, or `2020-01.xlsx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I already have this code, I'll just put it here in case you can modify it for your needs.  It is language (English) dependent as written.

```
:: get year, month, day for today
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('"echo.|date"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/.- " %%A in ("%Date:* =%") do (
        set %%a=%%A&set %%b=%%B&set %%c=%%C)
    )
)

set /a "yy=10000%yy% %% 10000 %% 2000 + 2000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"

:: yy is the 4 digit year presumed to be between year 2000 and year 2999; mm is the month; and dd is the day

:: Add 1 month 
if /i %mm%==12 (
   set mm=0
   set /a yy+=1
)
set /a mm+=1

:: mm2 is zero-padded month

:: Pad
set mm2=0%mm%
set mm2=%mm2:~-2%
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my advice to use a more suitable scripting language, and based aroung the fact you did not respond to my additional question via comment, here is a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) suggestion:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path "." -Filter "????-??" |
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -And $_.Name -Match "^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}$"} |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$(([DateTime]$_.Name).AddMonths(1)).ToString('yyyy-MM')}
```

If you really do have extensions, then you'll need to adjust the `-Filter` string pattern and incorporate `.BaseName`, and both `.BaseName` and `.Extension` instead of using `.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

---

For bat using independent date/time layout with **`wmic`**

```bat
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f ^tokens^=1^delims^=. %%i in ('"wmic OS Get localdatetime|findstr [0-9]"')do set "_dt=%%i"
if "!_dt:~4,2!" == "12" (set "_m=101" && set /a "_y=!_dt:~0,4!+1") else (set /a "_m=!_dt:~4,2!+101"
set "_y=!_dt:~0,4!") && set "_dn=!_y!-!_m:~1!") && for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /b  "*_"')do (
rename "%%~dpnF" "!_dn!")
```

---

- :: Result for today 2019-11-14 ::

```bat
 rename "2019_11" "2019-12"
```

---